# build dynamic string efficiently tsql

Tags: string, t-sql, char

I need to build a string in tsql which is a repetition of a given char
for example if I have inputs

```
@in char,@len int
```

and `in = 'x' ,len = 7`
the result will be

```
xxxxxxx
```

Comment: I wonder what you mean by efficiently though. What did you have in mind that you thought would be inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select replicate(@in,@len)
```